# What's wrong with my INSERT ~ SELECT ~ ON DUPLICATE KEY query on MySql?

Tags: mysql, duplicates, mariadb

Hello, everybody.

I've made a query that use INSERT .. UPDATE .. ON DUPLICATE.

But query that I made didn't work because syntax problem and I don't know why!

Here's what I tried to do.

**What I try to do is to give three 'magic_potion' to every account.**

First, I made two tables.

```
CREATE TABLE account(
    account_no INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    account_id VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
    account_pw VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(account_no)
);

CREATE TABLE item(
    item_no INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    account_id VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
    item_name VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
    item_count SMALLINT NOT NULL,
    item_status SMALLINT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(item_no)
);
```

Second, I put three account for test.

```
INSERT INTO account (account_id, account_pw) VALUES ('James', MD5('James')), ('Andy', MD5('James')), ('Angela', MD5('James'));
```

Third, I gave magic_potion to every account.

```
INSERT
INTO    item
SELECT  NULL, A.account_id, item_name, item_count, item_status
FROM    account A
        CROSS JOIN (SELECT 'magic_potion' AS item_name, 3 AS item_count, 1 AS item_status) B;
```

fourth, I put another account.

```
INSERT INTO account (account_id, account_pw) VALUES ('Judy', MD5('Judy')), ('Tom', MD5('Tom'));
```

fifth, Now, I want to give(=INSERT) two 'magic_potion' to newly added account and want to add(=UPDATE) one 'magic_potion' to previous account. So I made below query.

```
INSERT
INTO    item
SELECT  NULL, A.account_id, item_name, item_count, item_status
FROM    account A
        CROSS JOIN (SELECT 'magic_potion' AS item_name, 3 AS item_count, 1 AS item_status) B
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE item_name = 'magic_potion', item_count = item_count + 1, item_status = 1;
```

**But this query didn't work. System message said,**

```
Error code: 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'KEY UPDATE item_name = 'magic_potion', item_count = item_count + 1, item_status ' at line 6
```

I don't know what's wrong with my query.

Please, help me.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax error is easy -- `[CROSS] JOIN` can take an optional `ON` clause, so the parser thinks `ON DUPLICATE ...` is such a clause. To avoid the syntax error, you need to enclose the `SELECT` in brackets:

```
INSERT
INTO    item (
   SELECT  NULL, A.account_id, item_name, item_count, item_status
   FROM    account A
        CROSS JOIN (SELECT 'magic_potion' AS item_name, 3 AS item_count, 1 AS item_status) B
) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE item_name = 'magic_potion', item_count = item_count + 1, item_status = 1;
```

For a note, `CROSS` is redundant here.

Then you'll hit a context problem (ambiguous `item_count`). You don't need to solve it yet, because the query won't do what you expect anyway. It will never reach the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` clause, because your only unique key is the primary key `item_no`, and you are inserting `NULL` into it, which means it will be always generated by auto-increment -- that is, you'll keep inserting rows every time.

There are different solutions for this, depending on what exactly you want to achieve -- you can modify the query, or you can add a `UNIQUE KEY` on whichever field or combination is supposed to be unique in that table (maybe it's `account_id`, or maybe it's a combination `account_id` + `item_name` -- it's unclear from the data sample).

Comment: I fixed the query and also solved the context problem that you pointed. And the query works perfect. I just wanted the answer that makes my query works. But you also shared the valuable knowledge. I really appreciate that. Thank you.